# FluentNHibernate: LazyLoad and Fetch

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

in fluent nhibernate I can set Fetch.Something and Not.LazyLoad to a Reference or HasMany. What will happen if I use both?

How these two reflects to querying data in these three ways?

```
class UserMap
{
   HasMany(x=>x.Contacts). (Fetch or Not.LazyLoad)
   References(x=>x.Supervisor). (Fetch or Not.LazyLoad)
}

session.Query<User>();
session.Query<User>().FetchMany(x=>x.Contacts);
session.Get<User>(ID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Fetch` is not taken into account for Query/HQL. So, immediately after running the query, it will try to fetch your `Not.LazyLoad` properties **one by one**.

In general, disabling lazy loading is a bad idea in 99% of the cases. Suggested read: [NHibernate is lazy, just live with it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)

Comment: It does work for `Get()`, and I'm not sure about Criteria/QueryOver. It's still not a good idea. Use ad-hoc `Fetch/FetchMany` statements in your queries when needed and set reasonable batch sizes for fetching entities and collections.